# how to enable extension (openssl,...) without access to php.ini?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, email, gmail

I'm using codeigniter for sending mail but i have problems with my shared host, because I can't access php.ini so i have these errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465
(Connection timed out)
Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

I used .htaccess too with this content:

```
php_extension openssl.so
```

But I got this error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable
>       to complete your request.
>       More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>       Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying 
>       to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I've also read so many topics about this problem but none of them solved mine. 
Now , I don't know what i should do!

**Update :**
I found something in my host , I've been more confused! I wrote this:

```
if (extension_loaded('openssl')) 
{
    echo "enabled";     
}
die();
```

So why do I receive these errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465
(Connection timed out)
Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Comment: probably not possible, unless they've left `dl()` open, which is not guaranteed to work anyways.

Comment: I've used this function in this way `dl('php_openssl.dll');` but I've got this on my host error log : `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function dl()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using my host secured mail server instead of Gmail. I didn't find anyway to send mail through gmail!

Answer (score 0):

php has `dl()` to enable extension at runtime 
see http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

> dl — Loads a PHP extension at runtime

Try like this

```
 function load_lib($n, $f = null)
 {
  return extension_loaded($n) or dl(((PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX === 'dll') ? 'php_' : '') . ($f ? $f : $n) . '.' . PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX);
 }

load_lib('openssl');
```

Comment: I've used this function too, I've got this on my host error log : `PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl()`

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL has to be [compiled with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php), so you're probably not going to have that option with shared hosting.

Try switching to SendGrid - they have a [free usage tier](https://sendgrid.com/user/signup) that allows you to send 400 emails a day and extensive [example code for PHP](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/php.html).

Comment: I wrote important part of my code based on sending mails through my host,I prefer to find a way to solve this problem instead of using another thing.